# tengo un problema agrupando y ordenando en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

pongo en contexto: tengo una base de datos en la cual tengo una tabla en la que se guardan los detalles de las ventas, entonces necesito hacer una consulta que me entregue por día las ventas de cada producto con su respectiva cantidad sumada (considerando que el producto se puede vender muchas veces en el día en documentos distintos) y así en un rango de fecha que yo estime las consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
select codigo_producto, descripcion_producto ,cantidad_vendida, fecha_venta 
from detalle_venta 
where  fecha_venta between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
order by day(fecha_venta);
```

y me da como resultado los siguiente: filtro bien por día pero necesito sumar las cantidades vendidas y agrupar los códigos para que por día me entregue los productos con sus cantidades vendidas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al agrupar por código y sumar sus cantidades no me resulta que se me arroja un solo producto de todos los arrojados por la consulta y la idea es que agrupe y sume solo lo del día correspondiente

Comment: Y como estas haciendo ese query que agrupa?

Comment: de esta forma select codigo_producto, descripcion_producto ,sum(cantidad_vendida), fecha_venta from detalle_venta where  fecha_venta between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31' group by codigo_producto; pero pierdo el filtro del dia y me deja solo un producto agrupado y sumado la idea es que me arroje ademas el mismo producto agrupado y sumado por dia pero en varios dias ademas

Comment: Si quieres agrupar por fecha, debes agregar la columna de la fecha al group by de este modo: `... group by codigo_producto, fecha_venta`, si he entendido bien, pues tu forma de preguntar no es que sea demasiado clara.

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario, es dificil leer codigo o errores en comentarios.. usa el boton [edit] y agrega a la pregunta tu problema especificio...

Answer (score 0):

Esta query te permite agrupar por fecha y código de producto y ambos totalizados, con la idea de que puedas saber cuanto vendiste de cada producto en una fecha determinada.

```sql
SELECT fecha_venta, day(fecha_venta), codigo_producto, descripcion_producto, SUM(cantidad_vendida)
FROM detalle_venta 
WHERE fecha_venta BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
GROUP BY fecha_venta, codigo_producto;
```

Aunque no entiendo el porque de la agrupación por día, ya que si tienes varios meses te los va a agrupar por el número de día mezclando los meses, por eso es preferible agrupar por fecha.

Espero haberte ayudado!